# Disable underlining Kali Linux terminal / command line

Tags: shell-script, shell, terminal, kali-linux

Some text is being underlined in terminal, which is very annoying as one doesn't know if there is underscore or not:

[image]

How can I disable underlining? Tried to search google/stack, but no luck. Thanks.

Comment: what is value of `PS1` ? have you tried simplyfying it ?

Comment: "Read-and-type" is highly error-prone.  Use "Copy-and-paste."

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I just use a different shell, but in this case you can edit `.zshrc` in your home dir

- Look for the `ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES` configs, and take out underlines where appropriate...although I think you want `ZSH_HIGHLIGHT_STYLES[path]`
- I unset that, and was good to go (don't forget to source `.zshrc` once you're done editing)

Answer (score 0):

This is set up in the default user .zshrc like so:

```
. /usr/share/zsh-syntax-highlighting/zsh-syntax-highlighting.zsh
```

So change that to your own file, comment it out, or edit the file under /usr/share. Or kill your .zshrc file completely (select '0' when it asks to generate it)..